# Reference on complex cobordism

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, cobordism, orientation

I am trying to study a little of algebraic cobordism and I lack background from the classic setting. Hence, I am looking for a textbook or expository writing covering the basics of complex cobordism.

> **Do you know any suitable reference for the basics of complex cobordism?**

If possible, I would like the reference to cover a particular result. Let $E$ be a spectrum representing a cohomology theory and $MU$ the spectrum representing complex cobordism. As an analogy with the algebraic case, it should hold that
$$
E^*(MU)\simeq E^*(pt)[[c_1,c_2, \ldots]]
$$
where $c_i$ are the universal Chern classes. In other words, $E^*(MU)\simeq E^*(Gr)$ where $Gr$ denotes the infinite Grassmanian. If possible, I would like the reference to cover such result and its surroundings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is worked out in part 2 of

> *Adams, J. F.*, Stable homotopy and generalised homology, Chicago Lectures in Mathematics. Chicago - London: The University of Chicago Press. X, 373 p. £ 3.00 (1974). [ZBL0309.55016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0309.55016).

(note that to understand part 2 you need to have read part 3 first. Yeah, I know)

In particular the result you want is true only for *complex orientable* cohomology theories (those theories for which we can define $c_1$). This is to be expected, since what you want is essentially a version of the Thom isomorphism, that should hold only if the vector bundle is orientable for your cohomology theory.

Also, Adams works on homology rather than cohomology (it is a lot more convenient when having non-finite spaces like $BU_n$), but of course once you've proven you have a Thom class, the Thom isomorphism theorem holds in cohomology as well, thus proving the statement you're after.